# How to implement GA Events?

Tags: magento2, google-analytics

I have a requirement to add GA Events throughout the Website.

I found this plugin

http://www.anowave.com/marketplace/magento-extensions/magento-google-analytics-event-track/

Found this article is as well.

http://claudiucreanga.github.io/analytics/magento-analytics-event-tracking.html

Better to use Plugin or do custom way?

Answer (score 0):

Calling on plugin/custom, is  depends on your. If you have magento coding knowledge then suggest to use  custom.

Plugin means you need extra code and need to understand the code of that module.